# C++: Initialize a variable of a specific type, logic. Consise way of approaching these problems

Tags: c++

I have this problem generally, but my specific example is:
When dealing with .wav data,for 16 bit waves, one uses a signed integer, whereas the 8 bit waves are unsigned.

I would like to do something like the following:

```
if (bytesPerSample == 2){
      int16_t* buffer = new int16_t[1];
} else if (bytesPerSample == 1){
      uint8_t* buffer = new uint8_t[1];
} else {
      cout << "bytesPerSample: " << bytesPerSample << " is unsupported"  << endl;
}
```

Which I know is invalid, because the variable declared inside the scope of the if statement is destroyed when the block is exited.

I also know I could initialize both and then I could create 2 if statements and copy the rest of my code twice, change variable names and then execute one block only if #bytes is 2 and the other if #bytes is 2.   However, this method is not concise and can lead to me introducing issues as I change the second code block around.

Is there any concise method of specify the use of a variable of identical name but different type, for multiple potential type cases?

Comment: Have you considered templates?

Comment: With different types for buffer you're doomed to differences in the code all the way through. I'd probably have a templated function and something looking like `if (bytesPerSample == 2){ do_stuff<int16_t>(); } else if  (bytesPerSample == 1){ do_stuff<uint8_t>();} else...`

Comment: Yes, you can use templates.  Alternatively you can use unions.  Another approach that's pretty common for audio is to read the entire buffer as char with correct alignment, perform any swizzles for endinanness correction, and then reinterpret_cast the buffer to the correct type.

Comment: @paddy Could you provide an example of how a union would help me here?  I'm actually not sure what the purpose of Unions are, actually, which indicates I'm probably missing how you intend for me to use the union to approach this category of problem.

Comment: `union { int16_t* i16; uint8_t* u8; } buffer;` would store a single pointer, which at runtime you initialize based on the underlying datatype, and which you then use only with the member that you initialized (as per the rules of union usage) -- [consult the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union).  Since you always know the datatype because that's a prerequisite for doing anything, that shouldn't be a problem.  This is a handy way to keep your stuff in one place.  Beyond this, using function templates for common operations would be a reasonable idea.

Comment: Wrap it in a class and use polymorphism. Start with a purely `virtual` interface that defines generic, sample-size-independent operations on the buffer, but doesn’t own a physical buffer and cannot be instantiated. Next create two implementations that actually own buffers, with appropriate method overloads for their sample sizes. Ideally, the two implementations would (and probably *should*) be instantiations of a common template to maximize code reuse, with the sample size / type as its template parameter(s). Or maybe use a `std::variant` intsead, which is a C++-friendly kind of `union`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++17's `std::variant` type can hold multiple data types in the same space. You can then use `std::visit` to dispatch based on the type inside.

If you combine this with templates, you only have to write one version of each function that processes the variable.

```cpp
template <typename T>
void processSamples(const std::vector<T>& buffer) { 
  /* do your processing here */ 
}

std::variant<
  std::vector<uint8_t>,
  std::vector<uint16_t>> buffer;

if (bytesPerSample == 2) {
  buffer = std::vector<uint16_t>(numSamples);
} else if (bytesPerSample == 1) {
  buffer = std::vector<uint8_t>(numSamples);
}

std::visit([](const auto& buffer) { processSamples(buffer); }, buffer);
```

`std::visit` isn't magic. It uses a data structure similar to a tagged union: there is a field that indicates which type is currently stored, and a union with the different datatypes. When you call `std::visit`, the template function generates, when optimized, something roughly equivalent to a switch which tests the type and calls a different function for each option:

```cpp
void processSamples(uint8_t*);
void processSamples(uint16_t*);

struct Buffer {
  int bytesPerSample;
  union {
    uint8_t* u8;
    uin16_t* u16;
  }
}

Buffer buffer;
buffer.bytesPerSample = bytesPerSample;

if (buffer.bytesPerSample == 2) {
  buffer.u16 = new uint16_t[16000];
} else if (buffer.bytesPerSample == 1) {
  buffer.u8 = new uint8_t[16000];
}

if (buffer.bytesPerSample == 2) {
  processSamples(buffer.u16);
} else if (buffer.bytesPerSample == 1) {
  processSamples(buffer.u8);
}
```

...except when you use `std::variant`, everything is type-safe, accepts non-trivial types, and you don't have to check each switch block for exhaustiveness when you make a change.

If you do not have C++17, there are C++11 compatible implementations:

https://github.com/mpark/variant